# How to prevent file-system manipulation while a compiled-output file execution?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, file-permissions

Trying to create a server that **compiles and runs code submitted by users**. How can I run the executable output (compiled from code, unreliable) on the server-side, without affecting my codebase (binary executable itself)?

Is there any hack that can **deny file-system manipulations while executing the output**? Some permissions while running the `./blahblah.out` - command, or some other hack?

There's always an option to make my server-side output accessible only from the root. But, Is there any other elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Sanitize your inputs, dear Johnny Drop Tables.

Comment: Certainly you should run the code in a secured virtual machine or a container. The filesystem manipulation is not the only danger and disabling all writes will probably make your system to fail.